# Is this sentence grammatical, 'Are you saying, in your usual circumspect manner, that it isn't be a good idea?'?

Tags: grammar

> Are you saying, in your usual circumspect manner, that it **isn't be** a good idea?

*(from [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/circumspect))*

[image]

Why does it have two be's?

Comment: That's a mistake (in Collins Dictionary!)

Comment: If the dictionary has a "contact us" link do please report this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely an error in the dictionary. Searching for the segment "in your usual circumspect manner" leads to a result in Google Books for Follow the Sharks by William G. Tapply -

> "You're not planning to talk to Darryl Bond, are you?"
>
> "You seem to be implying, in your usual circumspect manner, that perhaps it might not be a wonderful idea."

I'd hazard a guess that Collins took this sentence for their example and then edited it to get rid of unnecessary fluff, but were a little careless in their editing, leaving that extraneous "be".

Answer (score 3):

This sentence is not correct. It should be "Are you saying... that it **isn't** a good idea?" (present tense) or "Are you saying... that it **wouldn't be** a good idea?" (conditional).